# How to do "not" without "!" in C

Tags: c, logic

In my programming class we are not allowed to use || && and ! for this assignment. How can you do a "not" statement without the use of !? Also, how to do && would be useful but I think I can figure it out.

(we can use % / * pow abs ln + -)

Comment: Please use % / * pow abs ln + - No if, else, or == sorry for any confusion. Also the values will be 0 to 4.

Comment: The ever changing question. It still seems ill defined to me.

Comment: re-write !(variable % 4) without the !. Use only % / * ln abs + -

Comment: Can you use ~ | & or ^ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
1-(abs(abs(a+1) - abs(a-1))/2)
```

Explanation:

```
int not(int a){
    int b = abs(a+1) - abs(a-1);
    //b is either -2, 0 or 2 depending on whether a was <0, ==0 or >0.
    int c = abs(b) / 2;
    //c is either 0 or 1 depending on whether b was zero or non-zero
    return 1-c;
    //return 1 if a is 0 or 0 if a is 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`!a` is equivalent to `1-a`, provided `a` is guaranteed to take only the values 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!x) { }
```

is the same as

```
if (x==0) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

(!x) is equivalent to (x?0:1) or (x==0)

Answer (score 1):

- How can you do a "not" statement without the use of !? Also, how to
  do && would be useful but I think I can figure it out.

Answering exact question: use standard macros `not`,`and` etc. Just don't forget to `#include <iso646.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, things like:

```
if(a != b){
   //do stuff
}
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
if(a == b){} else {
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Super easy simple way,

```
If(x == y) {
    //Don't do something 
 } 
 Else{
     //do something
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`!(variable % 4)` can be written as `"\1\0\0"[abs(variable%4)]`.

variable % 4 can only result in the integer values {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3} for any integer value of variable.

Since there are only 7 possible values, we can use a lookup table of the results.

The result of ! on these values is:

- -3 -> 0
- -2 -> 0
- -1 -> 0
- 0 -> 1
- 1 -> 0
- 2 -> 0
- 3 -> 0

To avoid having to deal with negative indexing, we'll abs the result, so we only see 0-3.

A simple way to represent this lookup table is a literal string: "\1\0\0". We use octal escape sequences for the values. The value at 0 is 1, the value at 1 is 0, etc. C strings have an implicit 0 (NUL) as the final char, and since the last value we need is 0, I didn't explicitly include that.

If you can't use square brackets, you can also write it like this: `*("\1\0\0" + abs(variable%4))`